# rails: how to list checkboxes in index view via bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I use Rails 4.2 and Bootstrap 4 alpha.
At the moment i have a list view (index.html.haml) with the value "false" for boolean attributes (eg. "Leseexemplar-relevant").

```
.row
  %table.table.table-sm.table-striped.table-hover.genres
    %thead
      %tr
        %th= Role.human_attribute_name('name')
        %th= Role.human_attribute_name('reading_copy_relevant')
        %th= Role.human_attribute_name('ksk_mandatory')
        %th= Role.human_attribute_name('annotation')
        %th
    %tbody
      - @roles.each do |role|
        %tr
          %td= role.name
          %td.boolean= role.reading_copy_relevant
          %td.boolean= role.ksk_mandatory
          %td= role.annotation
          %td
            = link_to edit_role_path(role), class: "btn btn-sm btn-default" do
              = icon('pencil')
            = link_to role, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => t('notices.confirm') }, class: "btn btn-sm btn-danger" do
              = icon('trash')

= link_to I18n.t('role.new'), new_role_path, class: "btn btn-primary-outline"
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

How can i manage to show - instead of the string "false" in the list view -  an unchecked checkbox when false and checked checkbox when true which are disabled so that the user can't check it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A html input-checkbox can be pre-checked through the `checked` attribute.

Do it like this:

```
      %td.boolean
        - if role.ksk_mandatory
          %input{ name: "ksk_mandatory", type: "checkbox", checked: "checked", disabled: "disabled"}/
        - else
          %input{ name: "ksk_mandatory", type: "checkbox", disabled: "disabled"}          
      %td.boolean
        - if role.reading_copy_relevant
          %input{ name: "reading_copy_relevant", type: "checkbox", checked: "checked", disabled: "disabled"}/
        - else
          %input{ name: "reading_copy_relevant", type: "checkbox", disabled: "disabled"}
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Phil, it helped :)

Comment: No problem :)
Remember to accept the answer/upvote if it helped. Enjoy your code!

Answer (score 0):

After some research i found a more rails way to get rid of the conditional cases and be more dry:

```
  %td.boolean
    = check_box_tag "ksk_mandatory", role.ksk_mandatory, role.ksk_mandatory, disabled: true
  %td.boolean
    = check_box_tag "reading_copy_relevant", role.reading_copy_relevant, role.reading_copy_relevant, disabled: true
```